# How to conditionally transform JSON based on body response in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I Want to have an Azure Logic App that receives HTTP data from multiple device types.

Each device has different body JSON schema structure.

Base on the response body (structure or specific value) I want to execute specific Liquid Map so that the result will be normalized response.

(Assume that I cannot check on HTTP headers...)

[image]

Is there a better pattern than Logic App?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a basic json schema with atleast one field that could identify where the call came from (caller should send that field in the body) and based on that field parse the incoming json against a more comprehensive schema (format 1, 2 etc).

However, I would recommend creating separate logic apps if there is a major diff b/w input posted from the sources. It is not a good practice to have different flows based on the caller. Logic app should have minimal logic. Your approach might be not be good in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the workaround that you can try.

Here is my logic app
[image]

I have considered a sample data to explain this in a better way.
Here is the data that I'm sending to the HTTP Trigger:-

```
{
  "devices": [
    {
      "device_number": 1,
      "device_type": "mobile",
      "device_name": "MobileA"
    },
    {
      "device_number": 2,
      "device_type": "desktop",
      "device_name": "DesktopA"
    },
    {
      "device_number": 3,
      "device_type": "tablet",
      "device_name": "TabletA"
    },
    {
      "device_number": 4,
      "device_type": "desktop",
      "device_name": "DesktopB"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I'm trying to parse the whole data that I'm sending for future use and performing some functions which segregates the json into **device_number**, **device_type** and **device_name**.

[image]

Here is the schema that I'm using to parse that data that is sent to the Http Trigger

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "devices": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "device_number": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "device_type": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "device_name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "device_number",
                    "device_type",
                    "device_name"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the next step I'm parsing the Data for your understanding but this is completely avoidable when you are storing the whole data into arrays

[image]

For combining or normalizing the results we can either use a compose connector and save to storage account else we can also directly send the same data directly using cosmos db `Create or update document` connector.

[image]

Here is the codeview of my logic app:-

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": {
                    "DevicesInformation": [
                        {
                            "DeviceNames": "@{variables('DeviceName')}",
                            "DeviceNumbers": "@{variables('DeviceNumber')}",
                            "DeviceTypes": "@{variables('DeviceType')}"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_DeviceName": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ],
                    "Parse_DeviceNumber": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ],
                    "Parse_DeviceType": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Create_or_update_document_(V3)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "DevicesInformation": [
                            {
                                "DeviceNames": "@{variables('DeviceName')}",
                                "DeviceNumbers": "@{variables('DeviceNumber')}",
                                "DeviceTypes": "@{variables('DeviceType')}"
                            }
                        ],
                        "id": "@{guid()}"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['documentdb_1']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/cosmosdb/@{encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings')}/dbs/@{encodeURIComponent('container2408')}/colls/@{encodeURIComponent('@devices')}/docs"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_DeviceNumber_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "DeviceNumber",
                            "value": "@items('For_each')?['device_number']"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_Data')?['devices']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_DeviceNumber": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "For_each_2": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_DeviceType_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "DeviceType",
                            "value": "@items('For_each_2')?['device_type']"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_Data')?['devices']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_DeviceType": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "For_each_3": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_DeviceName_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "DeviceName",
                            "value": "@items('For_each_3')?['device_name']"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_Data')?['devices']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_DeviceName": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_DeviceName": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "DeviceName",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_Data": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_DeviceNumber": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "DeviceNumber",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_Data": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_DeviceType": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "DeviceType",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_Data": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_Data": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@triggerBody()",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "devices": {
                                "items": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "device_name": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "device_number": {
                                            "type": "integer"
                                        },
                                        "device_type": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "device_number",
                                        "device_type",
                                        "device_name"
                                    ],
                                    "type": "object"
                                },
                                "type": "array"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Parse_DeviceName": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@variables('DeviceName')",
                    "schema": {
                        "items": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "type": "array"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each_3": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Parse_DeviceNumber": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@variables('DeviceNumber')",
                    "schema": {
                        "items": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "type": "array"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Parse_DeviceType": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@variables('DeviceType')",
                    "schema": {
                        "items": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "type": "array"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "documentdb_1": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/resourceGroups/<YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/documentdb-1",
                    "connectionName": "documentdb-1",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northcentralus/managedApis/documentdb"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```